# Unity: Finding Lowest Vertices on Mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a very newbie to using unity and C#. I have a question about spawning an object on the lowest Y coordinate on the mesh.

1. How to get the lowest Y vertices with other coordinates to spawn an object at that point.

Thank you in advance everyone :)

```cs
public Mesh terrain;
public GameObject agents;

void Start()

Mesh terrain = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Vector3[] meshVertices = terrain.vertices;

float minY = float.MinValue;
int count = terrain.vertexCount;
List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
terrain.GetVertices(vertices);

for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
{
    Vector3 pos = vertices[i];
    minY = Mathf.Min(pos.y,-pos.y);
    Vector3 position = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[i]);

    if (position.y == minY)
    {
        Instantiate(agents, position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

terrain.RecalculateBounds();
```

Comment: Do you know how to find the minimum value in a list?  Take a look [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1403515/how-to-find-the-minimum-number-in-a-float-array-c.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an answer for you that summarizes a large part of the code, all this is possible thanks to `system.linq`, the following code sorts vertices by y coordinate and puts them in a position list, just enough Set `list[0]` as position. The other vertices are also arranged in order, which is an advantage.

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

```cs
public void Start()
{
    var meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

    var list = meshFilter.mesh.vertices.Select(transform.TransformPoint).OrderBy(v => v.y).ToList();
    
    Debug.Log(list[0]); // lowest position
    
    Debug.Log(list.Last()); // highest position
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a minimum value, then you need to start with something that's so big that *anything* will be less than that. Something like `float.MaxValue`. Then you need to go through *all* the points and compare your current minimum to the running minimum and cache the current point if it's less. Once you're done with *all* the points then you can use your cached point as the instantiation location. Consider the following:

```
public Mesh terrain;
public GameObject agents;

void Start()
{
    Mesh terrain = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    Vector3[] meshVertices = terrain.vertices;

    float minY = float.MaxValue; // <--- Change
    Vector3 minimumVertex; // <--- Change
    int count = terrain.vertexCount;
    List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    terrain.GetVertices(vertices);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
    {
        // Vector3 pos = vertices[i];   // <--- Change
        // minY = Mathf.Min(pos.y,-pos.y);   // <--- Change
        Vector3 position = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[i]);

        // if (position.y == minY)   // <--- Change
        if(position.y < minY)   // <--- Change
        {
            minY = position.y;   // <--- Change
            minimumVertex = position;   // <--- Change
            //Instantiate(agents, position, Quaternion.identity);   // <--- Change
        }
    }
    Instantiate(agents, minimumVertex, Quaternion.identity);   // <--- Change

    terrain.RecalculateBounds();       
}
```